# Why this MYSQLi INSERT query fails without error or exception

Tags: php, mysqli, error-handling

I recently changed server and now certain mysqli queries are failing without notice of any kind.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($h, $u, $p, $db);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    error_log("Connect failed: %s\n" .  mysqli_connect_error());
}

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, 
                                            firstName,
                                            lastName, 
                                            phone) 
                                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("sssi", $email, $firstName, $lastName, $phone);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    error_log('[INSERT]errno: %d, error: %s', $mysqli->errno, $mysqli->error);
}
```

error_logs are never called (but other error_log() work fine). 
mysqli SELECT queries work fine. All INSERT / UPDATE queries all fail with no error.

The only change is possibly a MySQLi version change between servers.

Comment: is it really necessary to put the query in the if condition?

Comment: Certain queries or all queries?

Comment: For anyone encountering similar problems with behaviour changes between servers, the issue here was that mysql on the new server was set to STRICT mode so wouldn't accept INSERT without default values.

Comment: Also, although there was a hint at the answer buried in the answer to the supposed duplicate question, this is a different question with a clear concise answer. The 'duplicate' question was giving an error for starters.

Comment: I marked an answer that answered the question fully and would be concise and helpful to others. You marked this as a duplicate of another question which is mostly irrelevant. It it quite obvious this is not a duplicate.

Comment: There is not a single word in the marked answer regarding strict mode. A lie is a sin, mind you.

Comment: The question is not asking why it failed, but why there was no error reported. The marked answer explains why: because the check needs to be on 'execute', not 'prepare'. You deep seated anger issues don't help others here, keep your emotionally charged comments to yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your query with this instead. I've removed your `prepare()` method from the `if` statement, and put the execution of it there instead.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, firstName, lastName, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssi", $email, $firstName, $lastName, $phone);

if($stmt->execute()){ // if the query successfully executes
    echo "success";
} else {
    // display error
}
```

This should fix your problem, and hopefully it helps you out! If you have any problems; leave a comment!

Comment: @YourCommonSense huh?

Comment: Don't post "answers" saying "give it a shot". Wild guess should go in the comments.

Comment: @YourCommonSense it's literally just a saying. Not really a valid reason to down-vote. Down-vote if the code provided is shifty or doesn't work, not if the way it's provided is not worded to your standard (unless of course it's a bad explanation).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a gambling site where you *bet* an answer and see if it worked.

Comment: @YourCommonSense did I say it was? I simply provided an alternative to his code, I'm not "_betting_" on anything.

Comment: You *did* that. You posted a code without any explanation.

Comment: I agree that your approach could help. but technically it cannot be qualified as an answer

Comment: @YourCommonSense well then tell me I should provide an explanation, not that I shouldn't "_bet_" on my answers. and even with a down-vote? That's petty as dude. At least suggest to change it before doing so, so that I can at least learn from it. :/ Being an og StackOverflow user, you should know to do that first

Comment: @YourCommonSense we're not all professionals like you, are we? also, what are you basing your assumption off of? And, why are you being so childish